# Directx 11 spheres

Tags: geometry, directx-11, culling, frustum

I'm looking for an efficient way to display lots of spheres using directx 11. The spheres are defined by `(x,y,z,r)` where `(x,y,z)` are coordinates in space and `r` is the radius. I want to display only the spheres that can be seen, meaning that spheres that are not in the field of view and spheres that are too small to be seen wouldn't be drawn. However, if a group of spheres smaller than one pixel is at least as big as one pixel, then I want to display the most predominant color. Spheres have only one color and different levels of transparency. Any help would be appreciated and incomplete answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need several things. First an indexed unit sphere geometry, second a buffer to store the sphere instance properties ( position, radius and color ) and third a small buffer for the API parameters yet to come. The three combines in a single 'ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexedInstancedIndirect'

The remaining question is "how to feed the instance buffer ?". cpu is easy, just apply frustum culling, sort back to front because of the transparency and apply a merge based on the screen projection, update the buffer and use 'ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexedInstanced'.

gpu version will do the same thing with compute shaders but will be harder to implement. The advantage, zero cpu/gpu synchronization and should support far more instance.